# I have lost the subwoofer's speakers and cables, what can I do?

Tags: cable, speakers, sound-system

About 15 years ago I bought a great subwoofer of the model [Altec Lansing ATP3 3-Piece Speaker System](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00004XRED).

[image]

[image]

Since then I have lost the subwoofer's speakers and cables, what can I do?

I recall that the subwoofer had four cables:

- Power cable
- A cable going from the subwoofer to the personal computer
- A cable going from the subwoofer to the primary speaker (from which sound volume could be adjusted)
- A cable going from the subwoofer to the secondary speaker

I have already bought a new subwoofer but if I can save this one, I'd be glad.

Comment: Model? What connectors are on each unit? IF the Power Socket and the Amp is in the Sub (judging by it receiving the signal from the PC, likely through a commonly available cable that plugs into a 3.5mm (common PC port) or 6.5mm Audio Jack socket), Likely then the Sub to Speaker2 would be a simple cable you could buy/make up yourself (Again, identify the connectors and google cables for them). However, Sub to Speaker1 will likely be more complex as there will be wires for the volume control.

Comment: @Stax I have updated with all details I currently figure.

Comment: Looks like: Left is an RCA Socket. Middle: 6 pin Mini Din Line Circular Socket. Right 3.5mm Mini Jack Stereo Audio socket. You will need the PLUGS for these. You haven't mentioned the other side of the cables, but they're probably the same plugs. Cont'd.....

Comment: RCA sockets and plugs and even cables are still fairly common at Jaycar type shops (which I'd suggest you visit with the units to make sure), and more so on Amazon. DIN connectors less so, although I think this particular one may be the old mouse/keyboard pc standard and thus more common still. I haven't noticed double ended 6 pin cables, so you may have to make this up yourself which could be rather tricky if you don't have some electrical experience.  Jack stereo connectors and cables still Very common (just don't confuse with the 2.5mm or mono versions.)

Answer (score 0):

as a die-hard last resort and you can't buy them new or second hand, buy the parts from Jaycar, and make your own cables, the Din plug (one with all the multiple pins) should just match the pins on the other end, the others look just like standard 3.5 mm or 6.5 mm audio cables, to be sure if you can chase up a circuit schematics for it, but usually it is rare for wires to be crossed over to a different pin in any lead or cable.

Comment: The "INPUT" socket accepts a 3.5mm jack plug. The "LEFT" socket is RCA. I have confirmed the look of this socket by comparing with my own similar era (different brand) speakers.